# Microsoft Web Deploy:

Tags: orchardcms, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy an Orchard website to a Windows 2008 R2 server using Microsoft web deploy. Web matrix is able to add the test files but as soon as it comes time to publish, I get the following error

> Unable to publish. Unable to publish.
>   Error detail:
>   (2011/12/10 05:59:03 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.StatusThreadHandler.CheckForException()
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Deployment.MsDeployWorker.Execute(Boolean pullback)
>   Missing source parameter 'Database Password' (Password for the Database Username.). This must be set for successful synchronization.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ParameterizationRuleHandler.PreSync(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)

I am using Sql Compact but I can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: "Missing source parameter 'Database Password' (Password for the Database Username.). This must be set for successful synchronization." Doesn't that give you a hint?

Comment: Sure does, so where do I set the password, is is the database on my side or something to do with the server, is it related to SQL compact, the source paramater for what? As you can see, your comment doesn't help much at all.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't WebMatrix ask you for the connection string of the remote database? The password should be specified in there.
See http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1508/webmatrix-web-deploy-settings.aspx

Comment: Nope, it's disabled with the text "remote connection string not required"

Comment: Well, that's obviously wrong. You should take that to the WebMatrix forums or support.

Comment: I'm using SQL compact though, does that make any difference?

Comment: Locally you do, but the remote is not ce, otherwise you would not need to deploy the database other than by copying it.